# Sorting data using different criteria

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am having trouble with my following program C++ to sort data in these two functions:

- `sort_by_base_depth(SnowData _array[], int size)`
- `sort_by_date(SnowData _array[], int size)`

These are in my `class_tester.cpp` file (in comment blocks).

I would also like to print the data in my function:

```
void print_array_elements(SnowData _array[], int size)
```

and get and print the average of the snow totals in the function:

```
double get_average_base_depth(SnowData[], int)
```

#### `SnowData.h` (COMPLETED)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
/*
SnowData specification file
*/
class SnowData
{
private: 
    string snow_date;
    double base_depth;
public:
    SnowData();
    SnowData(string _date, double _inches);
    void print();
    string getSnow_date();
    double getBase_depth();
    void setBase_depth(double);
    void setSnowDate(string);
};
```

#### `SnowData.cpp` (COMPLETED)

```
#include "SnowData.h"
#include <iomanip>
/*
        Class default constructor
        Sets default values for class private variables
*/
SnowData::SnowData()
{
    snow_date = "";
    base_depth = 0;
}

/*
        OverLoaded constructor
        Parameters used to populate class private variables via set functions
*/
SnowData::SnowData(string _date, double _inches)
{
    setSnowDate(_date);
    base_depth = 0;
    setBase_depth(_inches);
}

/*
    print functions
    prints out class private variables
*/
void SnowData::print()
{
    cout << setw(15) << left << snow_date
            << setw(5) << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << right 
        << base_depth << endl;
}

/*
    accessor function for snow_date
*/
string SnowData::getSnow_date()
{
    return snow_date;
}

/*
    accessor function for base_depth
*/
double SnowData::getBase_depth()
{
    return base_depth;
}

/*
    mutator functions for base_depth.
    ensures that base_depth is not set to a negative value
*/
void SnowData::setBase_depth(double _inches)
{
    if (_inches >= 0)
        base_depth = _inches;
}

/*
        mutator function for snow_date
*/
void SnowData::setSnowDate(string _date)
{
    snow_date = _date;
}
```

#### `Class_Tester.cpp` (NOT FINISHED)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
#include "SnowData.h"

void print_array_elements(SnowData[], int);
//void sort_by_base_depth(SnowData[], int);
//void sort_by_date(SnowData[], int);
double get_average_base_depth(SnowData[], int);

int main()
{
    string dates[7] = { "Jan 15", "Jan 16" ,"Jan 17" ,"Jan 18" ,"Jan 19" ,"Jan 20","Jan 21" };
    double base_depth[7] = { 34.5, 23.6, 25.5, 31.5, 40.6, 30.9, 38.4 };

    SnowData jan_snow[7];
    int i = 0;
    for (auto &one_snow_day : jan_snow)
    {
        one_snow_day.setSnowDate(dates[i]);
        one_snow_day.setBase_depth(base_depth[i]);
        i++;
    }
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << showpoint;

    cout << " --- array after set functions invoked to populate array --\n";
    print_array_elements(jan_snow, 7);
    cout << "Average base depth for the period "
        << jan_snow[0].getSnow_date() << " - "
        << jan_snow[6].getSnow_date() << " : "
        << get_average_base_depth(jan_snow, 7) << endl;

    //sort_by_base_depth(jan_snow, 7);
    cout << " --- array after sort by base_depth --\n";
    print_array_elements(jan_snow, 7);

    //sort_by_date(jan_snow, 7);
    cout << " --- array after sort by date --\n";
    print_array_elements(jan_snow, 7);

    return 0;
}

double get_average_base_depth(SnowData _array[], int size)
{
    double total_depth = 0; //Initialize Accumulator

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        total_depth += i++;
    }
    return total_depth / 7;
/*
write code to iterate the array and add up base depth
from each individual array element
RANGE-BASED FOR LOOP CANNOT BE USED!
*/
}

void print_array_elements(SnowData _array[], int size)
{
    /*
    Write down the for Loop to print out elements from array
    RANGE-BASED FOR LOOP CANNOT BE USED!
    */
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
        cout << _array << index+1 << "   " ;
    cout << endl;
}

void sort_by_base_depth(SnowData _array[], int size)
{
           /*
           Write down sort code to sort by base depth of each element in the array.
          Use the getBase_depth() function of each array element
          */
}

void sort_by_date(SnowData _array[], int size)
{
      /*
       Write down sort code to sort by date of each element in the
       array. Use the getSnow_date() function of each array element
      */
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  If your question is about C++, do not tag it with C, nor vice versa.  Most of the time, the pair of tags ([tag:c] and [tag:c++]) are wrong and only one should be used.  Do not annoy the local population by dual-tagging.

Comment: Be cautious about using names starting with an underscore; they are mostly reserved for use by the implementation.  You often get away with using them, but you could run into problems later (moving the code to another system, or a new version of the compiler) and there's nothing that anyone will do except say "you shouldn't have used the reserved name".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::sort` to sort:

```
std::sort(begin(myArray), end(myArray));
```

This will use the default `<` operator to compare elements. It will sort into ascending order.

However your array contains `SnowData` objects, and there is no `<` operator for `SnowData`. You could create one by overriding `operator<` but instead we can use a lambda function.

Assuming you're using C++14:

```
// sort by base depth
std::sort(begin(myArray), end(myArray),
          [](auto a, auto b){
            return a.getBase_depth() <  b.getBase_depth();
          });
```

In C++11 you can't pass `auto` to a lambda, so it's wordier:

```
std::sort(begin(myArray), end(myArray),
          [](const SnowData& a, const SnowData& b){
            return a.getBase_depth() <  b.getBase_depth();
          });
```

It's possible to use `std::sort` with a custom predicate (a custom sorting function) before C++11 but it's much more tedious.

For sorting by date, that's harder, because you're storing the dates as strings. See if you can store it numerically instead, perhaps using `std::chrono`?